# MySQL Community edition as windows cluster role

Tags: mysql-5.7

I wanted to know if we can add MySQL Community edition instance as clustered role in Windows Failover Cluster.

I worked on MySQL 5.7 Enterprise edition setup as clustered role in a 2 node WSFC cluster. Never worked on a similar setup for community edition, so wanted to check with the community members.

Thanks